# Change the section color in europasscv "PERSONAL INFORMATION"

Tags: color, europasscv

For changing the color of section titles I do this in europasscv:

```
\newcommand{\mycvsection}[1]{\ecvsection{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}
```

This way the section title is black  when I use:

```
\mycvsection{Section Title}
```

But when I use:

```
\ecvpersonalinfo
```

I can not use the black. Can I somehow color the personal information section to?

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code? Not everybody knows `europasscv`

Answer (score 1):

An [example](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/europasscv/example/europasscv_en.tex) output:

[image]

The colour of "sections" within [`europasscv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/europasscv) is given by `ecvsectioncolor`. If you want this to be `black`, add

```
\colorlet{ecvsectioncolor}{black}
```

to your preamble. However, some things other than `\ecvsection`s also use `ecvsectioncolor`. Here's the output if you use the above change:

[image]

If you want it to affect "sections" only, you could patch `\ecvsectionstyle`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\ecvsectionstyle}{ecvsectioncolor}{black}{}{}
```

Here's the output if you use the above patch only:

[image]

---

Here is a list of the colours defined by `europasscv`, if you want to change more colours (taken from [`europasscv.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/europasscv/europasscv.cls)):

```
\definecolor{ecvrulecolor}{HTML}{398dc9}
\definecolor{ecvsectioncolor}{HTML}{0e4194}
\definecolor{ecvhighlightcolor}{HTML}{1593cb}
\definecolor{ecvtablebordercolor}{HTML}{c6c6c6}
\definecolor{ecvhighlightcellcolor}{HTML}{ebebeb}
\definecolor{ecvlanglinkcolor}{HTML}{000080}
\definecolor{ecvtextcolor}{HTML}{3e3a38}
```

Comment: I have a problem getting the SECTION headers of my Europass CV to appear bold in the europasscv package. Neither \bf nor \textbf{} seem to work.

Comment: @AlaguraajVH: Are you using `\ecvsection{\textbf{section}}`?

Comment: nope i don't any idea i didn't use that. i need to make that PERSONAL INFORMATION(section header) in BOLD . i had tried this " \colorlet{ecvsectioncolor}{black} " it helped me lot

Comment: @AlaguraajVH: For that specific section, you need to add `\makeatletter
\let\oldecv@infosectionkey\ecv@infosectionkey
\renewcommand{\ecv@infosectionkey}{\textbf{\oldecv@infosectionkey}}
\makeatother` to your preamble.

Comment: i'm new to LaTeX it's difficult for me to understand . i had tried this "
\makeatletter \let\oldecv@infosectionkey\ecv@infosectionkey \renewcommand{\ecv@infosectionkey}{\textbf{\oldecv@infosecti‌​onkey}} \makeatother  "and got an error message  as 1."! Undefined control sequence.", 2."! PACKAGE INPUTENC ERROR: UNICODE CHAR Â€‹ (U+200B)"

Comment: @AlaguraajVH: That error doesn't seem to relate to my suggestion. If you want, you can paste your code to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and supply a link here. We need something to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i had tried this "\colorlet{ecvsectioncolor}{black}" but only section has been changed to black . i would like to change the whole format in black and white.  is that possible ?

Comment: @AlaguraajVH: See the bottom of my updated answer; I've added the different colours/names that `europasscv` defines. You should be able to `\colorlet` all of these to `black`.